# CakePHP Find Query SUM() two fields from two different tables

Tags: cakephp, methods, find, sum

I am using CakePHP Find query to get `SUM()` from two diff fields in two diff db tables:

```
$total = $this->Model->find('all',array('fields' =>
array(
  'SUM(Model1.amount * Model2.purchase * Model3.rental * Model4.manu) as total'),
  'group' => array( 'Model.trackby_id' ) )
);
```

I have found `sum()` method useful for same tables two diff fields, but it does not seems working when two diff fields from diff tables.

Anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify your SQL fragment in the **fields** array in the parameters of the **find** method.

```
$total = $this->Model->find('all', array(
  'fields' => array(
    'SUM(Model.price + OtherModel.price) AS total'
  ),
  'group' => 'Model.id'
));
```

Comment: @iamtheladylegend it's definitely +. You should probably be grouping by your Model.id as well.

Comment: @iamtheladylegend Cake will produce a sql query similar to: **SELECT SUM(Model.id + OtherModel.id) AS Total FROM `Model` LEFT JOIN `OtherModel` ON (`Model`.`id` = `OtherModel`.`model_id`) GROUP BY Model.id`**